# Auto-renew a certificate every <= x days from creation using Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Azure Key Vault has an option to auto-renew certificate within x days **before expiry**. I need to auto-renew cert in Azure Key Vault x days **from creation**.

- As shown in the image below, there is no option in portal to do so.
- One way would be to leverage "Automatically renew at a given percentage lifetime". For that I would either need to understand lifetime of each certificate in Key Vault or set lifetime of each cert in Key Vault to be same to avoid confusion of setting how much percentage lifetime for which certificate.

Any suggestions on how to achieve it via some tool or scripts? Looking for a cleaner way than the one mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: As fra as I knew, now azure key vault does not provide  such policy to manage the certificate lifetime. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-rotate-certificates

Comment: @JimXu: Thanks for the comment. Agreed. I acknowledge that fact when I say "there is no option in portal to do so." Just looking for a tool or script that exists but I might not be aware of. I am also trying to develop a powershell script for the same if possible.

Comment: I think you can the certificate's start time, then get now time to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the expiration you should use along with the percentage of lifetime, but if you want more explicit control over when the certificates are renewed, perhaps consider a [scheduled trigger with an Azure Function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) or an [Azure Automation runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules).